# Draw AreaChart with google grpah api using json data

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization, json

i have a json array in the following format which i get in a ajax response

```
{"graph":[{"date_display":"2013-12-26","ticketss_sold_on_date":"3","money_earned":"468"}]}
```

the google api javascript part which draw tha graph takes the data in the following way

```
var sales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Day', 'Sales', ],
  ['Mon',  1000],
  ['Tue',  1170],
  ['Wed',  660],
  ['Thu',  1030],
  ['Fri',  2056],
  ['Sat',  1654],
  ['Sun',  969]
]);
```

pleae tell me how to pass my json array data to the above google.api code in the following format to

```
var sales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['DATE', 'Sales', ],
  ['date from json array ',  number of tickets sold from json array],
```

like

```
[2013-12-12, 15]
[2013-12-11, 10]
[2013-12-10, 18]
```

and so on....

```
]);
```

i am getting data by applying foreach method in jquery area in the follwoing way

```
    <script>
$.each(response.graph,function(i,el)
            {
                alert(el.date_display+' - '+el.ticketss_sold_on_date+' - '+el.money_earned);
            });

    </script>
```

but when i apply this each method in in above graph api, it gives me error..

How to pass my above json response array to google api to draw areachart.?

Comment: Do you want to input your dates as strings or Date objects?

Comment: Which one - strings or Dates?